# Download file from Webservice using React Native

Tags: react-native

I have written a webservice which is sending me excel file from server to download, I have a mobile Application written in React-Native and I want to download that file in my mobile application,
I tested my webservice in browser I am able to download the file, but how to do that in react-native.

My RestAPI accept some parameter in request and in return it will download the file.

I have tried `rn-fetch-blob` and `react-native-fs` but they gives are using direct path to download the image in my case my api is providing me the file.

I have search a lot but couldn't find anything related.

Can anyone help me how to implement in this in react-native.

Comment: rn-fetch-blob is good option to download file in react native.

Comment: yes but it doesn't give any option for the post request.

Comment: Yes there is option for post request.

Comment: can you send me a sample code

Comment: Yes,but i must want to confirm :-You want to download excel file from your webserver with Post request?

Comment: yes, you can check this url `https://fdd3f189.ngrok.io/test`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197578/discussion-between-kabir-and-suneel).